# Generating input fields using PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm attempting to generate a bunch of inputs of the same name, and saving it to an sql table. The issue i'm having is, my code works for about 4 of the inputs, then the rest nothing happens.

Code thats generating the inputs:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
            echo "      ID: <input name=\"IDadd[]\" type=\"text\"> \n"; 
            echo "      Name: <input name=\"Nameadd[]\" type=\"text\"> \n"; 
            echo "      Job: <select name='Jobadd[]'>\n"; 
            echo "      <option value='Tech'>Tech</option>\n";
            echo "      <option value='Check-In'>Check-In</option>\n";
            echo "      <option value='Inventory'>Inventory</option>\n"; 
            echo "      <option value='Beats'>Beats</option>\n"; 
            echo "      <option value='Computers'>Computers</option>\n";
            echo "      <option value='IOS'>IOS</option>\n";
            echo "      <option value='Remarketing'>Remarketing</option>\n";   
            echo "      </select> \n";
            echo "<br><br>";
        }
```

Code that should be sorting it out and saving it:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'newEmployee' ] ) )
                            {
                            $index = 0;
                                foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                                   $userId = $_POST['IDadd'][$index];
                                   $userName = $_POST['Nameadd'][$index];
                                   if (empty($_POST['Nameadd'][$index])) {
                                    return;
                                  }
                                   $userJob = $_POST['Jobadd'][$index];
                                   $index++;
                                   $sql = "INSERT INTO Employee (userId, Name, Job, Week)
                                    VALUES ('$userId', '$userName', '$userJob', '$currentWeekIs')";
                                    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                }
                                if($sql) // will return true if succefull else it will return false
                                    {
                                            mysqli_close( $con );
                                            sleep(4);
                                            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=add.php">';
                                    }
                            }
```

--EDIT

So this should work then?

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'newEmployee' ] ) )
                            {

                                if (!empty($_POST['IDadd'])) {
                                    // loop through the keys of one of the arrays
                                    foreach (array_keys($_POST['IDadd']) as $index) {
                                        $userId = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['IDadd'][$index]);
                                        $userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Nameadd'][$index]);
                                        $userJob = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['Jobadd'][$index]);
                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO Employee (userId, Name, Job, Week)
                                        VALUES ('$userId', '$userName', '$userJob', '$currentWeekIs')";
                                        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                    }
                                    if($sql) // will return true if succefull else it will return false
                                    {
                                            mysqli_close( $con );
                                            sleep(4);
                                            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=add.php">';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: No, it has 3x10 inputs. Its in a for loop so the input boxes are generated 10 times each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `foreach` is looping through `$_POST['IDadd']`, `$_POST['Nameadd']` and `$_POST['Jobadd']`, not the contents of those arrays. Just checkout the contents of `$key`.

What you need to do is make sure they aren't empty and then loop through the contents:

```
// I'm just showing checking all the arrays aren't empty
// you'll also want to check if they have the same length
if (!empty($_POST['IDadd']) && ...) {
    // loop through the keys of one of the arrays
    foreach (array_keys($_POST['IDadd']) as $index) {
        $userId = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['IDadd'][$index]);
        // ...
    }
}
```

You should also look into using prepared statements to lessen the chance of SQL injection.

Comment: But wouldn't this be getting the contents of each one? Thats kind of the point of the foreach loop.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop's `$key` would be set to the string `IDadd` in the first run through, then `Nameaad` the second time (order may be different), so it will loop for only the number of `$_POST` variables that are being returned, not for the number of elements in the contents of those. So what you need to do is loop through the contents of the arrays. I suppose the best way of thinking about it is that `$_POST` is a multi-dimential array in this instance.

Comment: So, with your example above, I will have to loop through each one with 3 different foreach loops? How would I handle saving that to a database then?

Comment: No, you just need to determine the array keys, hence the `array_keys()` call. If they all have the same number of elements, it doesn't matter which you use. All the rest of the code would be the same, except you don't need to increment the `$index` variable.

Comment: Also, SQL injection isn't really a worry of mine currently, because it is a private system that is password guarded.

Comment: @Kevin_Nagurski UPDATE: The code did not work, it doesn't save any of them now.

Comment: I think its because the ID is an input. So it isn't based off the array in any way.

Comment: @TimothyLee are you getting any errors? The `IDadd` is written as `name="IDadd[]", so `$_POST['IDadd']` should be an array as well.